# Not able to update and retrieve both image and text from mongoDB

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, mongodb, ejs

**Javascript code**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const multer = require("multer");
const {GridFsStorage} = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
const Grid = require("gridfs-stream");
const methodOverride = require("method-override");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
const findOrCreate = require("mongoose-findorcreate")

const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

const mongoURI = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/userDB';
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);
//mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/userDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});

let posts = [];

let gfs, gridfsBucket;

conn.once("open",() => {
  gridfsBucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db, {
        bucketName: "upload"
      });
  gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection("upload");
});

const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoURI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if(err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString("hex") + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: "upload"
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});
const upload = multer({storage});

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("review");
});

app.post("/review", (req, res) => {
  const post = {
    name: req.body.userName,
    hotel: req.body.hotelName,
    address: req.body.hotelAddress,
    star: req.body.rating,
    userexperience: req.body.experience
  };

  posts.push(post);
  //res.json({ file: req.file});
  res.redirect("/content");
});

app.get("/content", function(req, res){
  gfs.files.find().toArray((err, files) => {
    // Check if files
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      res.render("content", {files: false});
    } else {
      files.map(file => {
        if(file.contentType === "image/jpeg" || file.contentType === "image/png"){
          file.isImage = true;
        }else{
          file.isImage = false;
        }
      });
      res.render("content", {files: files});
    }
  });

});

app.get("/content", function(req, res){
  res.render("content", {posts: posts});
});



//@route GET /files
//@desc  Display all files in JSON
app.get("/files", (req, res) => {
  gfs.files.find().toArray((err, files) => {
    // Check if files
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: "No files exist"
      });
    }

    // Files exist
    return res.json(files);
  });
});

app.get("/files/:filename", (req, res) => {
  gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename }, (err, file) => {
    // Check if file
    if (!file || file.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: "No file exists"
      });
    }
    // File exists
    return res.json(file);
  });
});

// @route GET /image/:filename
// @desc Display Image
app.get("/image/:filename", (req, res) => {
  gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename }, (err, file) => {
    // Check if file
    if (!file || file.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: "No file exists"
      });
    }

    // Check if image
    if (file.contentType === "image/jpeg" || file.contentType === "image/png") {
      // Read output to browser
      const readstream = gridfsBucket.openDownloadStreamByName(file.filename);
      readstream.pipe(res);
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({
        err: "Not an image"
      });
    }
  });
});



// Server setup
app.listen(3000, function(req, res) {
  console.log("Connected on port:3000");
});
```

**HTML Code where the review should be displayed - this is content page**

```
<section class="review-content">
    <% posts.forEach(function(post){ %>
  <h6><b>User Name:</b><%=post.name%></h6>
  <h5><b>Hotel Name:</b><%=post.hotel%></h5>
  <p><b>Hotel Address:</b><%=post.address%></p>
  <%if(post.star == 5){%>
      <p><b>Rating: </b>⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐ - Luxury</p>
  <%}%>
  <%if(post.star == 4){%>
      <p><b>Rating: </b>⭐⭐⭐⭐ - First Class</p>
  <%}%>
  <%if(post.star == 3){%>
      <p><b>Rating: </b>⭐⭐⭐ - Comfort</p>
  <%}%>
  <%if(post.star == 2){%>
      <p><b>Rating: </b>⭐⭐ - Standard</p>
  <%}%>
  <%if(post.star == 1){%>
      <p><b>Rating: </b>⭐ - Basic</p>
  <%}%>
  <% if(files){ %>
          <% files.forEach(function(file) { %>

              <% if(file.isImage) { %>
                <img src="image/<%= file.filename %>" alt="">
                <% } %>

            <% }) %>
              <% } else { %>
                <p>No files to show</p>
                <% } %




  <p><b>User experience:</b><%=post.userexperience%></p>
  <%});%>
```

**HTML Code where the review should be displayed - this is review page**

```
<form class="" action="/review" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="submit.php">
    <section class="review-section-height">


      <section class="review-section">
        <div class="review-section-div">
          <div class="user-name-review">
            <label for="hotel-name">User Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="user-id-name" name="userName" placeholder="User Name" size="40"><br>
          </div>
          <div class="review-hotel-name">


            <label for="hotel-name">Hotel Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="hotel-id-name" name="hotelName" placeholder="Hotel Name" size="40"><br>
          </div>
          <div class="hotel-address-div">


            <label for="hotel-address-name">Hotel Address:</label>
            <input type="text" id="hotel-id-address" name="hotelAddress" placeholder="Hotel Address" size="40"><br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section class="star-rating-section">




        <div class="food-experience-div">


          <h5>Rate your experience in hotel:</h5>
          <div class="rating">

            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" id="5"><label for="5">☆</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" id="4"><label for="4">☆</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" id="3"><label for="3">☆</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" id="2"><label for="2">☆</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" id="1"><label for="1">☆</label>

          </div>
        </div>


      </section>
    </section>


    <div class="container">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="image">
          <img width="50%" height="450vh" src="" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="icon">
            <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            No file chosen, yet!
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="cancel-btn">
          <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="file-name">
          File name here
        </div>
      </div>
      <input name="file" id="default-btnn" type="file" >
    </div>



    <section class="overall-user-review">
      <div class="overall-user-review-div">
        <label for="experience-write-box">Write your experience:</label><br>
        <textarea class="experience-textarea" name="experience" rows="10" cols="47" placeholder="Elaborate your experince in the hotel..."></textarea>
      </div>

    </section>


<script>
      const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
      const fileName = document.querySelector(".file-name");
      const defaultBtn = document.querySelector("#default-btnn");
      const customBtn = document.querySelector("#custom-btn");
      const cancelBtn = document.querySelector("#cancel-btn i");
      const img = document.querySelector("img");
      let regExp = /[0-9a-zA-Z\^\&\'\@\{\}\[\]\,\$\=\!\-\#\(\)\.\%\+\~\_ ]+$/;

      function defaultBtnActive() {
        defaultBtnn.click();
      }
      defaultBtn.addEventListener("change", function() {
        const file = this.files[0];
        if (file) {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function() {
            const result = reader.result;
            img.src = result;
            wrapper.classList.add("active");
          }
          cancelBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
            img.src = "";
            wrapper.classList.remove("active");
          })
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
        if (this.value) {
          let valueStore = this.value.match(regExp);
          fileName.textContent = valueStore;
        }
      });
    </script>
```

[[Output at hyper terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjKjo.png)]
[[Output at localhost at chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQm8z.png)]
Looking forward if someone can help me with this...
I need both image and text to be rendered on the screen
I am stuck with this problem for several days...
It's saying posts not defined... at eval... and so on...
Hoping a positive reply from developers...
Thank you for your help...

Comment: That error output indicates the problem is at line 221 of HotelAide-Finale/index.js

Comment: Can you please suggest me what to be replaced...

Comment: not really, I don't have a way to correlate that error with any of the code examples in the question.